# memsql create function scheduled

Tags: singlestore

I need to create a function that runs from time to time inside memsql, I am using the syntax below but returns error.

```
CREATE 
    EVENT   clean_resumo_posicao 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE   STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO BEGIN

        -- delete resumo_posicao when inserted more than 10 minutes
            delete from evento.resumo_posicao   ; 
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemSQL does not support CREATE EVENT. You can schedule a query to run periodically with an external scheduling tool.